# Override Delphi SOAP Response

Tags: delphi, soap, web, serialization

Is it possible to override Delphi SOAP *TWebResponse* in a SOAP Web Application?
Or (better) override the serialization of the response?

I need to create the response object from a custom serializer (that I already have) and I would like to pass this XML serialization to the client.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will help you, but whenever I need to modify some output of my SOAP-response, this is what I do:
I am using DELPHI XE2 and in the unit where I have my webmodule, there is a HTTPSoapPascalInvoker1.
In the Objektinspector I create an AfterDispatchevent which will look something like:

```
procedure TWebModule1.HTTPSoapPascalInvoker1AfterDispatchEvent( const MethodName: string; SOAPResponse: TStream);
```

Inside this event I can now actually inspect the content of the stream and also modify the stream as needed.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the event `TWebModule.OnBeforeDispatch` and set `Handled` to `true` after processing the current request and creating your custom XML and writing it to the response:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request:
    TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  str: TStream;
begin
  str:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MyCustomRequestProcessing(Request, str);
    Response.SendStream(str);
    Handled := True;
  finally
    str.Free;
  end;
end;
```